# Moving background image with mouse –CSS and JS – Multiple horizontal stacked DIVs

Tags: javascript, css, animation

Hello need some help stacking multiple div tags inside single container div horizontally.  Each with their own scrollable BKG image.  The code attached with some simple CSS works great for 1st div.  Prob is I can’t get other divs on the right to move correctly.  The BKG image moves off screen and all over.   CSS is using inline-block. The Divs stack nicely, move well with browser size changes.

```
$(".download_content_02").mousemove(function( event ) {

var containerWidth = $(this).innerWidth(),
    containerHeight = $(this).innerHeight(),
    mousePositionX = (event.pageX / containerWidth) * 100,
    mousePositionY = (event.pageY /containerHeight) * 100;

$(this).css('background-position', mousePositionX + '%' + ' ' + mousePositionY + '%');

});
```

Answer (score 3):

that is because the mouse event attributes `pageX` and `pageY` are calculated from the edge of whole page. You need reduce the offset of the `div.download_content_02`

```
$(".download_content_02").mousemove(function(event) {
  var containerWidth = $(this).innerWidth(),
    containerHeight = $(this).innerHeight(),
    containerOffsetLeft = $(this).offset().left, // container left offset
    containerOffsetTop = $(this).offset().top, // container top offset
    mousePositionX = ((event.pageX - containerOffsetLeft) / containerWidth) * 100,
    mousePositionY = ((event.pageY - containerOffsetTop) / containerHeight) * 100;

  $(this).css('background-position', mousePositionX + '%' + ' ' + mousePositionY + '%');

})
```

Here is [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/x1zupwmw/1/).

Hope this is what you need.

**Update**

Add `mouseleave` event listener to reset background image position.

Comment: This is wonderful, thank you for taking the time to create the example.  If you wouldn’t mind do you know how I can get the image to reset to a default position?  Maybe its orig position before they scrub over it.  Like float: left or something similar?

Comment: I think you can add another event handler for `mouseleave` event, and then reset the position of background image. For initial, you can use css `background-position` to set the default position.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you

Comment: I strongly recommend moving ontainerWidth, containerHeight, containerOffsetLeft, containerOffsetTop under mouseenter event (I'd make it an object for closure purposes), not mousemove. Otherwise you are bubbling up much more by getting the same numbers over and over again. I tested it and it ate 25%-45% much less memory on my machine.